# Wordpress admin user capabilities not working

Tags: wordpress, wp-admin, wordpress-roles

We had an attack on our Wordpress site and the attacker managed to create a new admin user.
Fortunatelly they didn't delete the 2 admin users that already existed, so we still had access to our Wordpress dashboard and we managed to delete the attackers' admin user.

Ever since neither of the 2 admin users we already had seem to have normal admin capabilities:

1. We get the following message "WordPress 6.3.2 is available! Please notify the site administrator."
2. We are unable to update themes and plugins
3. We have stopped receiving Wordpress emails on the email address that was originally set

We tried to edit the admin users' capabilities through the user roles tab but even with everything selected there is no change.
Any ideas?
Thank you